# Buildr, RSpec—pass build parameter to test

Tags: ruby, rspec, buildr

I have »buildr« »buildfile« which triggers some »rspec« tests. I would like to pass some path parameters to the tests, so that It wont cause trouble to load test-resources files. In the »buildfile« I have got this code to trigger the tests:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.add_setting :spec_resources_dir, :default => _(:src, 'spec', 'ruby', 'resources')
end

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:run_rspec) do |t|
  t.pattern = 'src/spec/**/*_spec.rb'
end
task test => [:run_rspec]
```

But if I try to retrieve the value in the specfile like this:

```
RSpec.configuration.spec_resources_dir
```

I get this error

```
undefined method `spec_resources_dir' […] (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec's rake task runs the specs in a separate process, so configuration you do with `RSpec.configure` in the buildfile will not be visible to the running specs.

Two suggestions for passing info from the buildfile to your spec task:

1. Generate a `spec_helper` and require it from your specs (or via rspec's `-r` command line option and the `rspec_opts` config parameter on `RSpec::Core::RakeTask`). You could use buildr's filtering to substitute values from the buildfile into the helper.
2. Set values in `ENV` and then read them out from your specs. Environment variables are shared from parent to child processes.

By request, an example for #1:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = "-r '#{_(:target, 'spec_helper.rb')}'"
end
```

This assumes that you (probably in another task) generate the spec helper into `_(:target, 'spec_helper.rb')`

Comment: that looks very much like the answer! Could please drop a line of code to show how to use the `rspec_opts` of the rake task, I am new to ruby, rspec and so on, and the documentation does not show an example… Thanks in ahead!

Comment: Thank You, very kind to post the example!